# How to limit what Editors see in the admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a site with a bunch of custom post types, and a few plugins.  I would like it so that editors ONLY have access to see posts when they visit a site.

Does anyone know of how I can do that?  I understand I can add capability functions to the custom post types, but I want to be able to just hid everything BUT posts when they log in.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u do not want to hack a lot into function.php of your wordpress, 
I would like to suggest you use:

Admin Menu Editor PLUGIN, Lets you directly edit the WordPress admin menu. You can re-order, hide or rename existing menus, add custom menus and more.

which works great for me.

But anyway if u want to hack using if-else to display diffent contents can use below code

```
// can reuse this custom function
function get_current_user_role() {
global $wp_roles;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$roles = $current_user->roles;
$role = array_shift($roles);
return isset($wp_roles->role_names[$role]) ? translate_user_role($wp_roles->role_names[$role] ) : false;
}
```

then

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
$currentrole =  get_current_user_role();
if( $currentrole == "Editors"){    // could be any role even custom roles.
   // see what kind of contents;
}else{
   // see other kinds of contents;
}
```

I've been using this kind of code in one of my project, it's working well, so if maybe can help u.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think the plugin would do the trick... either way I'd have to set specifically what the users are to see so the plugin works, even though I would avoid like to use a plugin it seems to what I need pretty well.

Comment: feeling very glad when i receive your comment. Thank you for your comment too. @Mixmastermiike